# JQuery, remove element from string

Tags: jquery

I have a string:

```
var s = '<h1>heading</h1><p>para</p>';
```

and I want to remove the `h1` element from it.
Ive tried:

```
$(s).remove('h1');
```

but s still contains the `h1` element
Ive also tried:

```
s = $(s).remove('h1');
```

and

```
$('h1', s).remove();
```

and

```
$('h1', $(s)).remove();
```

etc etc etc

Any ideas?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Update**: I see you just changed the question. Now the solution would be this:

```
var s = '<h1>heading</h1><p>para</p>';

var $s = $(s).not('h1');

$('body').append($s);​
```

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/q9crX/19/

Because you now have more than one "top level" element in the jQuery object, you can use `.not()` (which is basically the opposite of `.filter()`) to remove the `h1`.

It would be the same as doing `$(s).filter(':not(h1)');`

- http://api.jquery.com/not/
- http://api.jquery.com/filter/

---

**Original answer**

```
$(s).find('h1').remove();
```

So if you were to append the result to the `body`, you could do:

```
var s = '<div><h1>heading</h1><p>para</p></div>';

var $s = $(s).find('h1').remove().end();

$('body').append($s);​
```

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/q9crX/

Comment: @alex - That is because you need to store the jQuery object you create in a variable. When you wrap it with `$(s)` and do `.find('h1').remove()`, you're not modifying the original string.

Comment: @patrick Ah yeah, whoops, I guess that was a big oversight on my behalf! Anyway, have a +1 :)

Comment: Thanks @alex. :o) I was actually stuck at first on why it was appending the `<h1>` that I had just removed, but then remembered that I needed to use `.end()` to get back to the `<div>`.

Comment: Hi, sorry I made a mistake in my question (now updated). It turns out the the string is not wrapper in a div.

Comment: What if element you want to remove is inside another element? Let's say I want to remove <table> element from <div><table></table></div>, so there remains only <div></div>.