# String to jQuery object, how to remove elements

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to manipulate some html which is in a textarea (not part of the page) but I want to be able to perform jQuery functions on it.

Here I am trying to remove the div with the attr 'my_id' of 1234, but the resulting data remains the same?

```
var data = "<div>something<div my_id='1224'>blah</div><div my_id='1234'>xx123</div></div>";

var id = '1234';

$(data).remove('[my_id="'+id+'"]');

alert($(data).html());
```

Obviously just using alert for debugging.

Comment: Your question has sloved here:[enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331449/jquery-remove-element-from-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var data = "<div>something<div my_id='1224'>blah</div><div my_id='1234'>xx123</div></div>";

var id = '1234';

var $data = $(data);  // create elements from the string, and cache them

$data.find('[my_id="'+id+'"]').remove(); // find and remove the nested element

alert($data.html());  // alert the resulting HTML
```

1. You were giving `.remove()` a selector, which only works on top level elements. The targeted element is nested.
2. When you did `alert($(data).html());`, you were using the *original* string, which isn't modified. You need to create the elements, reference the jQuery object, do your manipulation, then use that same jQuery object to see the result.

Comment: On a side note, it's not a good idea to have id's start with an integer.

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder: Those aren't ID attributes. They're custom. ;)

Comment: In that case he should use the data attribute.

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder: Sure, that would be a good idea as it is valid HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Removing dom traversal of non-dom elements

Use the data prefix to put custom attributes on elements:

```
<div data-my_id='1224'
```

And then:

```
$(data).find('div[data-my_id="' + id + '"').remove();
```

Or more simply just use a regular id on the div you're targeting:

```
 <div id='1224'
```

Which can then be removed with:

```
$(data).find('#' + id).remove();
```

Comment: Did you test that before answering?

Comment: I guess I entered my first response without enough forethought

Comment: Sorry, but I've got to -1 this. You're trying to do DOM selections to find an element that isn't in the DOM.

Comment: @RightSaidFred - you're right, I fixed that, but I think the advice I gave him on using custom attributes was good.

Comment: Thanks guys, why was the use of my custom attribute selector incorrect? Or was it merely a matter of being more specific when putting the 'div' in-front?

Comment: @user1076568: It wasn't incorrect. I used your selector in my answer. But you needed to do a `.find()` to get the nested element. See point `1.`.

Comment: Yep roger that! Thanks again!

Comment: @RightSaidFred - isn't it bad form to use custom attributes like that?  Won't that cause problems in certain circumstances?  I'm not trying to argue, but I could have sworn I read/heard that somewhere

Comment: Well, maybe. Ultimately HTML5 allows for `data-` attributes, but in any browser that doesn't support them, they will be considered custom attributes anyway. But to future proof your code, `data-` attributes would be better. But yes, I think there may be some browser bugs, but jQuery takes care of those if so.

Comment: @RightSaidFred "but jQuery takes care of those if so" - indeed.

Comment: Yep, gotta know where the bugs are. Helps to know when it makes sense to use/not use jQuery.