# Using jquery toggle, after appending an element, how do i remove that element?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

How do i remove `var icon` element once i have appended it? the current method is not working.

i tried the way explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331449/jquery-remove-element-from-string) but it didnt work.

JQUERY

```
$('#edit').toggle(function(){
    $('#edit').text('Close');
    var icon='<i class="icon-remove"></i>';
    $('.para').append(icon);
}, function(){
    $('#edit').text('Edit');
    var $icon = $(icon).not('i');
    $('.para').append($icon);
});
```

this doesnt work either

```
    $('#edit').toggle(function(){
    $('#edit').text('Close');
    var icon='<i class="icon-remove"></i>';
    $('.para').append(icon);
}, function(){
    $('#edit').text('Edit');
    var icon='.remove';
    $('.para').remove(icon);
});
```

HTML/PHP

```
foreach ($users_tags as $key => $list) {
echo '<span>'.$list['tag_name'].'<span class="para"></span> </span>. ';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it like that

```
('#edit').toggle(function(){
    $('#edit').text('Close');
    var icon='<i class="icon-remove"></i>';
    $('.para').append(icon);
}, function(){
    $('#edit').text('Edit');
    var $icon = $('.icon-remove');
    $icon.remove();
});
```

Comment: don't forgot to approve answer for next users with same problem ;)