# How to get the clean "non-highlighted" code with prism.js

Tags: javascript, prism.js

I'm using prism.js to highlight some css in a `<pre contenteditable="true">` tag in a settup very similar to [this one](http://bililite.com/blog/blogfiles/prism/prismeditor.html).

On `keyup` I copy the code to a hidden `<textarea>` but the output is the highlighted text such as:

```
<span class="token selector">#description </span><span class="token punctuation">{</span><br>
<span class="token property">cursor</span><span class="token punctuation">:</span>
... etc.
```

Is there a way to get the *un-highlighted* text to be able to save it in its clean original format?

Comment: I'm currently using a solution like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18464575/746558

Comment: ... Also replaced '<br>' tags for "\n" lines or it would be one long string of CSS.