# Javascript String Replace span element by empty string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have HTML string in JS where I would like to remove the span element from it.

```
var HTML= '<div>test</div><p>test</p><span class="removedata">X</span><span>test</span><span class="removedata">X</span>';
```

After removing Span, it should be look like:

```
HTML= '<div>test</div><p>test</p><span>test</span>';
```

I have tried below JavaScript operation but does not work,

```
HTML = HTML.replace('/<span class="removedata">X</span>/g',"");
```

Any inputs?

Comment: Does it have to be with a regular expression?

Comment: Removing span from DOM is also an option instead of regex.

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18464432/how-to-remove-span-tag-from-the-string

Comment: Above span remove string is fixed. So you can share solution based on it. No, I don't need Regular expression.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The slash `/` is a special character** in [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) and you need to escape it `\/`:

```js
var html = '<div>test</div><p>test</p><span class="removedata">X</span><span>test</span><span class="removedata">X</span>';
var newHtml = html.replace(/<span class="removedata">X<\/span>/g, '');

console.log(newHtml); // "<div>test</div><p>test</p><span>test</span>"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to do it with `RegExp`.

```js
var str = '<div>test</div><p>test</p><span class="removedata">X</span><span>test</span><span class="removedata">X</span>',
    str2 = str.replace(/<span class="removedata">X<\/span>/g, '');
    console.log(str2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on a regular expression, you could

```
HTML = HTML.replace(/<\/?span class="removedata".[^>]*>/g, '');
```

Comment: This does not worked. I don't need to remove all span but span with class removedata.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var HTML= '<div>test</div><p>test</p><span class="removedata">X</span><span>test</span><span class="removedata">X</span>';

var htmlObj = $(HTML);
htmlObj = htmlObj.not(".removedata");

var htmlString = $('<div>').append(htmlObj).html();
console.log(htmlString);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the text, but a different approach would be also possible:

At some point you are adding the content of `HTML` to the DOM-tree. When you've done that you could also achieve the "removement" by doing the following:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("removedata");
elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The below could work.

```
var html = '<div>test</div><p>test</p><span class="removedata">X</span><span>test</span><span class="removedata">X</span>';
html = html.replace(/<span class="removedata">X<\/span>/g, '');
console.log(html);
```

You can use the below site if you are new to regex.

https://regex101.com/