# Edit results of outerHTML with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to read in the entire page's HTML (including the doctype) then remove a few parts of the page in order to pass it as a string via AJAX.

What I have so far is:

```
var page = doctype + document.documentElement.outerHTML;
```

This gives me the content that I want, but when I try to use jQuery's `.remove()` function, I'm getting `undefined is not a function`.

```
page.remove(".my-class");
```

I assume I'm doing something with the variable type wrong? How can I grab the full page source such that I can still manipulate it with jQuery?

Comment: Why would a jQuery method work on a non-jQuery object?

Comment: $(page).remove('my-class');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the html into a jQuery object in order to manipulate it. After you do that you can use the jQuery's [find method then remove method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3331449/188246) to remove elements that match `.my-class`:

```
var $page = $(doctype + document.documentElement.outerHTML);
$page.find(".my-class").remove();
```

After that you can get the resulting html by doing:

```
var htmlToSendViaAjax = $page[0].outerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manipulate HTML with jQuery, you have to call the jQuery constructor:

```
var page = $(doctype + document.documentElement.outerHTML);
page.remove(".my-class");
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that `page` is not a jQuery object and as such doesn't have methods like `.remove()`.

If you want the outerHTML with jQuery, you need to make a jQuery selection:

```
$("#selector");
$(document); // for the entire document
```

Then you can use a solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744207/jquery-outer-html) to get the outerHTML of the first element in the selection (you can use a `for` or `each` loop if you do it for lots of elements:

```
var $selection = $("#selector")
$selection[0].outerHTML;
```