# Access value of js object that has html

Tags: javascript, jquery

If we have a javascript object with html code like this:

`var elm = "<div id="a"> <div id="b"> <div id="c"> </div> </div> </div>";`

How can access `#a` via jquery?

for example `$(elm).addClass('.red')` doesn't work.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/ - specifically "Return a collection of matched elements either found in the DOM based on passed argument(s) or *created by passing an HTML string.*"

Comment: Well your string is invalid.

Comment: Never mind, I see what you did - escape double quotes inside your string or use single quotes to wrap it.

Answer (score 2):

> for example `$(elm).addClass('.red')` doesn't work.

Except that it does.

```js
var elm = '<div id="a"> <div id="b"> <div id="c"> </div> </div> </div>', 
    $elm = $(elm); 

$elm.addClass('red'); 
console.log($elm);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Output

```
Object { 0: <div#a.red>, length: 1 }
```

Edit:

Including my own comments here

> Never mind, I see what you did - escape double quotes inside your string or use single quotes to wrap it.

Comment: I was just going to post that. That's the answer! If you need more detailed info, check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331449/jquery-remove-element-from-string/3331459#3331459

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should not use double-quotes inside of sourounding double quotes.
**Change**

```
 var elm = "<div id="a"> <div id="b"> <div id="c"> </div> </div> </div>";
```

**to**

```
var elm = '<div id="a"> <div id="b"> <div id="c"> </div> </div> </div>';
```

Now `$(elm)` will be the div with id `#a`. Only if you are searching for child elements of $(elm) you can find those with for example `$(elm).find('#b')` while `$(elm).find('#a')` will give you no result since `#a` is no child of itself.